# Pass Function from Service file to components

Tags: angular, service

I am relatively new to angular and struggling to pass a function to components. I have a function that is currently stored in a service file that needs to be passed to a lot of component files, and then used in html ( via string interpolation).   An y help on how I would do this?.

Here is the service file and the function that needs to be passed to components

```
  text = {
    careHome: {
      resident: "Resident",
      carer: "Carer",
    },
    Domiciliary: {
      resident: "Client",
      carer: "Staff",
    },
    Hospital: {
      resident: "Patient",
      carer: "Nurse",
    },
  };

  careType = "Hospital";

  updateString(stringToChange: any) {
    let StringToReturn = this.text[this.careType][stringToChange];
    return StringToReturn;    

Here is the string interpolation 
<div>{{updateString('resident')}}<div>
```

I have tried passing it  using constructor but is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

- first you have to create the service, inject that in your component and then you can call your service function in component html.

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class YourService {

  constructor( ) { }

  text = {
    careHome: {
      resident: "Resident",
      carer: "Carer",
    },
    Domiciliary: {
      resident: "Client",
      carer: "Staff",
    },
    Hospital: {
      resident: "Patient",
      carer: "Nurse",
    },
  };

  careType = "Hospital";

  updateString(stringToChange: any) {
    let StringToReturn = this.text[this.careType][stringToChange];
    return StringToReturn;    
  }

  }
  ```
- in your component.

  constructor(private service: YourService) { }
- you can call then -

  {{this.service.updateString}}

Comment: If it is private you won't be able to call it inside of html

Comment: Even if change the constructor in the component to public when i add {{this.service.updateString('resident}} it is not showing any text

Answer (score 0):

To pass a function from a service to multiple components in Angular, you can use dependency injection. If you've already tried using the constructor and it's not working as expected, let's review the steps and see if there are any issues.

1. **Service:**

   Make sure your service is provided at the root level or in the module where your components are declared. This ensures that there's a single instance of the service available throughout your application.

   ```js
   // Your service
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

   @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root',
   })
   export class YourService {
     // ... your existing code

     updateString(stringToChange: any) {
       let StringToReturn = this.text[this.careType][stringToChange];
       return StringToReturn;
     }
   }
   ```
2. **Component:**

   Inject the service in your component's constructor.

   ```js
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { YourService } from 'path-to-your-service';

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-your-component',
     templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css'],
   })
   export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(private yourService: YourService) {}

     // ... other component code
   }
   ```
3. **HTML Template:**

   Use the service method in your component's HTML.

   ```html
   <div>{{ yourService.updateString('resident') }}</div>
   ```

If you've followed these steps and it's still not working, please provide more details.

Comment: Still not showing anything ( it should show the word patient)